# Compile issues dependency with gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to compile this repo from Github

https://github.com/juangilgithub/AirplayServer

But when I try to sync the project I receive this message from the console:

Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

I am new in Android Studio and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Regards

Comment: JCenter repository has been shut down, And the list of repositories is missing `mavenCentral()` repo in `build.gradle`. Not sure if all dependencies are available in Maven central.

Comment: With mavenCentral() it doesn't work but with  Google() I get  the same error: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
But if I go to the link I an download the grade 3.2.1 but I don't know how to use it.